# how to automatically add an image and name it to an xml file in android?

Tags: android, xml, events, handler

I was wondering suppose you are creating a space in an blank xml file to store attributes such as shirts  if you were to upload an image from your sd card, how would  you code the event handler for that?

Comment: If you are talking about in your `layout` file, you can't that doesn't get changed during runtime. There are other ways that you can display and store it but you would need to be more specific on what you want and supply relevant code

Comment: Can you show us what code you have to get started?